# C Calculator with a lot of functions in functions in functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, calculator

I had programmed first an easy calculator. Now I would like to outsource the individual program components in Functions. The Problem is the switch-part.The program always gives me the default message:Bad operator. Please take a look and give me some tipps.Is something wrong with the pointers and double-pointers?

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void newcalc(char*,double*,char*,double*);
double switchfunk(double**, char**, double**);
double readcalc(double**,char**,double**);
double addition(double,double);
double subtraction(double,double);
double multiplication(double,double);
double division(double,double);

int main()
{
    double a=0, b=0;
    char op='R', restart = 'Y';
    newcalc(&restart,&a,&op,&b);
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

double switchfunk(double** x, char** opp, double** y)
{
    printf("\n ---CALCULATOR--- \n\n\n");
    switch (**opp)
    {
        case '+':printf("%lf + %lf = %lf\n", **x, **y, addition(**x, **y)); break;
        case '-':printf("%lf - %lf = %lf\n", **x, **y, subtraction(**x, **y)); break;
        case '*':printf("%lf * %lf = %lf\n", **x, **y, multiplication(**x, **y)); break;
        case '/':printf("%lf / %lf = %lf\n", **x, **y, division(**x, **y)); break;
        default:printf("bad operator!");
    }
    return 0;
}

void newcalc(char* restart,double* x, char* opp, double* y)
{
    while (restart != (char*)'N')
    {
        readcalc(&x, &opp, &y);
        switchfunk(&x, &opp, &y);
        printf("New Calc? (Y,N) \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &restart);
        if (restart != (char*)'Y'&&restart != (char*)'N')
        {
            printf("Bad input!");
        }
    }
}

double readcalc(double** x,char** opp,double** y)
{
    printf("\n Type your calculation!(z.B.4+7)\n");
    scanf("%lf%c%lf",x,opp,y);
    return 0;
}

double addition(double a,double b)
{
    double c = 0;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}

double subtraction(double a, double b)
{
    double c = 0;
    c = a - b;
    return c;
}

double multiplication(double a, double b)
{
    double c = 0;
    c = a*b;
    return c;
}

double division(double a, double b)
{
    double c = 0;
    c = a / b;
    return c;
}
```

Best regards!

Comment: why you pass pointer and pointer and pointer and...so many pointer. just pass only `char` also enough.It will confuse you also.

Comment: Technically calling `fflush` on `stdin` is undefined behavior. Some platforms defined the behavior, but if you want your code to be portable then don't do it.

Comment: And why do you declare the variables locally in the `main` function, and pass them as pointers to the `newcalc` function, instead of just declaring the variables where they are needed (i.e. locally in the `newcalc` function)?

Comment: Use some array of function pointers.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what can i use istead to clean the buffer? Thx for your answer.

Comment: As far as the C standard goes, there's nothing. There are other ways to go around the problem if there being unwanted whitespace in the input buffer, for example you could tell `scanf` to read and discard possible leading whitespace by adding a single space in from of the format code, so you would have e.g. `scanf(" %c", restart);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misusing pointers and using addresses rather than the values themselves. Also, you are using pointers to pointers while you are not in need to do so. Take a look at the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void newcalc (char*,double*,char*,double*);
double switchfunk(double*, char*, double*);
double readcalc(double*,char*,double*);
double addition(double,double);
double subtraction(double,double);
double multiplication(double,double);
double division(double,double);

int main()
 {
    double a=0, b=0;
    char op='R', restart = 'Y';
    newcalc(&restart,&a,&op,&b);
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
return 0;
}
double switchfunk (double* x, char* opp, double* y)
{
    printf("\n ---CALCULATOR--- \n\n\n");
    switch ( *opp )
    {
        case '+':
                    printf("%lf + %lf = %lf\n", *x, *y, addition(*x, *y)); 
                    break;
        case '-':
                    printf("%lf - %lf = %lf\n", *x, *y, subtraction(*x, *y)); 
                    break;
        case '*':
                    printf("%lf * %lf = %lf\n", *x, *y, multiplication(*x, *y)); 
                    break;
        case '/':
                    printf("%lf / %lf = %lf\n", *x, *y, division(*x, *y));
                    break;
        default:printf("bad operator!");
    }

    return 0;
}
void newcalc(char* restart,double* x, char* opp, double* y)
{

    while ( *restart == 'Y' || *restart == 'y')
    {
        readcalc(x, opp, y);
        switchfunk(x, opp, y);
        printf("New Calc? (Y,N) \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", restart);
        // if (restart != (char*)'Y'&&restart != (char*)'N')
        // {
            // printf("Bad input!");
        // }
    }
}

double readcalc(double* x,char* opp,double* y)
{
    printf("\n Type your calculation!(z.B.4+7)\n");
    scanf("%lf%c%lf",x,opp,y);
    return 0;
}

double addition(double a,double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
double subtraction(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}
double multiplication(double a, double b)
{
    return a*b;
}
double division(double a, double b)
{
    return a / b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have so many problems in your code, most of them related to your use of pointers. Here's one problem:

In the `newcalc` function you have the following condition in a loop:

```
restart != (char*)'N'
```

That will *not* work as you expect, in fact it will *always* be true and give you an infinite loop.

The reason is that `restart` is a pointer which points to the location of the local `restart` variable in the `main` function. It will *never* be the same as `(char *) 'N'` (which is a pointer pointing to address `78`).

How to solve this specific problem? To start with, don't have it as an argument, declare it as a local (non-pointer!) variable:

```
char restart = 'y';
```

Then use it normally in the loop condition

```
while (restart == 'y' || restart == 'Y') { ... }
```

---

And to hint to more pointer problems, remember that [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) want a pointer to the variable where to store the value?

But in e.g. the `readcalc` function the variables `x`, `opp` and `y` are pointers to pointers to where the data should be stored, and yet you pass these pointers-to-pointer to `scanf`:

```
scanf("%lf%c%lf",x,opp,y);
```

Here, you *should* use pointers as argument to `readcalc` function, but not pointers-to-pointers.

In other words, it should be declared as

```
double readcalc(double*,char*,double*);
```

---

You most likely have many other problems with your (unnecessary) use of pointers and pointers-to-pointers, but these were the ones that really stood out.

Comment: `restart ` is a pointer to char. He is using the address while he should dereference it `*restart` to use it.

Comment: `restart` inside the function `newcalc()`

Comment: @CroCo And I question the *need* for it to be a pointer, there simply isn't any. Just as there isn't any need for it to be passed into the function as an argument.